# How do I get the int ASCII value of a character in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, ascii

How do I get the ASCII value as an int of a character in Cocoa? I found an answer for doing this in python, but I need to know how to do this in Cocoa. ( I am still a noob in Cocoa).
Python method:
use function ord() like this:

```
>>> ord('a')  
97
```

and also chr() for the other way around:

```
>>> chr(97)  
'a'
```

how do I do this in Cocoa?

Comment: `NSString` uses UTF-16 code units of type `unichar` for strings. They are already simple integer values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Character constants are already integers:

```
int aVal = 'a'; // a is 97, in the very likely event you're using ASCII or UTF-8.
```

This really doesn't have anything to do with Cocoa, which is a library.  It's part of C, so it's not specific to Objective-C either.

Comment: Wow! I told you I was a noob! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Cocoa, it depends on the language, simply in C or C++ make a cast to int to the char :)

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int number;
char foo = 'a';
number = (int)foo;

std::cout << number << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```